# Two questions about shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, i3

KDE is my current desktop and i3wm is my previous desktop. 
In KDE, when using the virtual desktop, I set `meta+1~9` to switch to virtual desktop 1~9. It works fine. In i3wm, double typing the same shortcuts, I can return the previous virtual desktop, such as `meta+1`(to d1), `meta+4`(to d4), `meta+4`(return to d1).

KDE do nothing when type the second `meta+4` How can I implement it in KDE?

My second question is how to use meta+enter to launch a console in KDE

Answer (score 0):

1. Closest thing available would be to set up a separate shortcut to return to the previous desktop, it's a KWin action called "Walk Through Desktops (Reverse)".
2. Set up a custom shortcut: System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts; Edit -> New -> Global Shortcut -> Command/URL.